# Getting cors error when api gateway deployed using SAM template

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have developed lambda functions in node.js and trying to deploy to **api gateway with proxy integration** using SAM templates.
my lambda functions are returning headers as mentioned in AWS documentation

```
const response = {
       statusCode: 200,
       headers: {
           "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
       },
       body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
   };
```

**template.yaml code**

```
GetClientFunction:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        CodeUri: functions/GetClient/
        Handler: index.handler
        Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetClientCustomFieldMap:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ClientApi # this is api with authorizer configured
            Path: api/Client/GetClient/{name}   
            Method: get
```

It is creating all resources which mentioned in the path like 'api', 'Client', 'GetClient' but not with **Options** method, also getting cors error. Tried multiple ways from stackoverflow but could not resolve it.
Followed this url as well [How to enable CORS with AWS SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065130/how-to-enable-cors-with-aws-sam)

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure Cors of the Api resource for the OPTIONS methods, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-cors

Comment: I did that, Seems it is issue with SAM templates. Posted a question in their GitHub forum. https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/2372